# ASP.NET Core 5.0 Localization Issue with Separate Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to use localization on the Asp.net core, and have separated the projects models and messages are different class library.

User model class:

```
public class User
{
    [Display(Name = "User_code_DisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(ResxUser))]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResxUser),ErrorMessageResourceName = "User_code_ErrorMessageMaxLength")]
    public string code { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User_Name_DisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(ResxUser))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResxUser),ErrorMessageResourceName = "User_Name_Required")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResxUser),ErrorMessageResourceName = "User_Name_ErrorMessageMaxLength")]
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.displayName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label input-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input asp-for="@Model.displayName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name *" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.displayName" class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.code" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label input-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input asp-for="@Model.code" class="form-control" placeholder="Code"  />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.code" class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Class library - messages - resource file:

[image]

`StartUp.cs`:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddRequestLocalization(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ta");
            x.ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders = true;
            x.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new("en"), new("en") };
            x.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new("ta"), new("en") };
            x.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new("te"), new("en") };
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRequestLocalization();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

I am trying to set default language load with tamil. It seems it was not accepted.

Comment: Hi @Prasad Raja, it works fine in my project that displays `Code`, `Name` when the page load. Did your view still display `User_code_DisplayName`?

Comment: @Rena when we are english language it was fine... i am trying to set default language with tamil.. but still it was showing as english... I am expecting default language should be  in tamil..